# Real Analysis: Quick Proof Verification using Mean Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, proof-verification, continuity

Let $f: \mathbb{R+} \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable such that $f'(x) \to 0$ as $x. \to \pm \infty$.  Show that the function g defined by $g(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$ tends to $0$ when x tends to $\ \infty$.

Proof: we apply the Value theorem on the interval $(x,x+1)$.  By the Mean value Theorem, since $f$ is differentiable and continuous on such an interval,
we know that there exists a $c_x$, where c depends on x so that $f'(c_x)=f(x+1)-f(x)/1. $  Thus $f'(c_x)$=$f(x+1)-f(x)$.  As x goes to $\ \infty$, $f'(c_x)$ goes to $f'(x)$ which goes to 0 by assumption.  Hence, we have $f(x+1)-f(x)$ tends to 0 when x tends to $\ \infty$.  Hence, we are done.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Most definitely the right idea, but I don't like the statement "As $x$ goes to $\infty$, $f'(c_x)$ goes to $f'(x)$. Perhaps you could flesh this statement out a little?

I would consider going back to $\varepsilon$-$N$ arguments. Fix $\varepsilon > 0$, and hence there must be some $N$ such that $x > N \implies |f'(x)| < \varepsilon$. That same $N$ should work to show $|f(x + 1) - f(x)| < \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct, but you need to word it carefully: you can't say that some quantity goes to $x$ as $x \to \infty$ because the limit cannot depend on $x$ (you probably meant 'behave like', sometimes denoted with a $\sim$, but such language is not very rigorous and is usually only found in more informal proofs).

Instead, you could say that since $g(x) = f'(c_x)$ and $c_x \in (x,x+1)$, therefore $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = \lim_{c_x \to \infty} f'(c_x) = 0$, and you are done. (The same thing for $-\infty$.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is something more rigorous.

Given $\varepsilon>0$, we know that there exists some $A>0$ such that :

$$\forall t\ge A,\vert f'(t)\vert\le\varepsilon$$

If $x\ge A$, applying the mean value theorem on $(x,x+1)$ leads to :

$$\exists c\in(x,x+1);\,f(x+1)-f(x)=f'(c)$$

Since $c\ge A$, we have $\vert f(x+1)-f(x)\vert\le\varepsilon$. This proves that $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to+\infty}(f(x+1)-f(x))=0}$

Answer (score 0):

yes, you are right, but note that you forgot to put ( and ) but because $x-(x+1)=1$ it doesn't matter.

anothing thing to note is that saying $c_x$ depends on $x$ is not a good way to put it, you can say that because $c_x\in(x,x+1)$ and when $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}$, $x$ and $x+1$ are the same you have $c_x=x$ for $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}$ and thus $g(x)=f'(c_x)$

---

you also can solve it without using the Mean value Theorem:

if $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x+k=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x$ for $k\in\Bbb R$ you have $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f'(x+k)=0$ thus there is no change in the value of $f(x)$ in the interval $[x,x+k]$ for $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}$ hence $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x+k)\implies\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)-f(x+k)=0$